# How can I update only the flash player for chromium when I have set the 'Automatically check for updates' as 'Never' ?

Tags: 14.04, google-chrome, flash, chromium

I have installed Ubuntu 14.04 today. I have installed only Chromium browser at it. As I don't want the different softwares in my operating system to get updated(as I want save my bandwidth), how can I update only the flash player of Chromium browser(to play songs on my browser online) ?

Does the 'Update Automatically' works for all the softwares of the Ubuntu or only for the Ubuntu operating system ?

I remember that, in order to save my bandwidth in Windows 7, I used to disable-update the operating system and different softwares explicitly. There was no option to disable-update the Google Chrome browser and I wanted just that browser to get updated(for better view of the webpages).

Comment: There's a difference between checking for and having updates installed automatically. Keep the check enabled, but do the installation yourself, if you want.

Comment: I have updated the 14.04(the updates were of about 500 MB) and all the softwares are working fast. The first tip to be given to any new Ubuntu user is to install the latest distro available, otherwise one would have to come to askubuntu again and again. Thanks and Regards to all.

Answer (score 1):

Which version of **flash** are you using ?

```
dpkg -l|grep flashplugin
```

It could be (1) *flashplugin-installer* or (2) *pepperflashplugin-nonfree*

For (1) run:

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install --reinstall flashplugin-installer
```

For (2) run:

```
sudo /usr/sbin/update-pepperflashplugin-nonfree --install
```

Note:
If you're using (1), I suggest you switch to (2) because it is the latest flash version; run:

```
sudo apt-get purge flashplugin-installer && sudo apt-get install pepperflashplugin-nonfree && sudo /usr/sbin/update-pepperflashplugin-nonfree --install
```

Comment: For this, do I need to enable the 'update automatically' option of Ubuntu 14.04 ? I don't want to exhaust my bandwidth on OS upgradation. :( Look at my comment to the previous answer.

Comment: no, you don't need to

Comment: Does the 'Update Automatically' works for all the softwares at the Ubuntu or only for the Ubuntu operating system ?I remember that, in order to save my bandwidth in Windows 7, I used to disable-update the operating system and different softwares explicitly. There was no option to disable-update the Google Chrome browser and I wanted just that browser to get updated(for better view of the webpages).

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following command to update the chromium browser in a cli(terminal):

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install chromium-browser
```

the apt-get install command updates the package to the latest available if a package is already installed.

As far as I know the flash player of chrome/chromium is built in and can't be updated separately.

Comment: Whenever I am opening Gaana.com, this website is showing a message that 'It seems you don't have latest flash player installed'. I know that this happens when you have not updated your browser. I have installed Chromium browser today. I want to listen to songs online, for that I will have to have 'the latest flash player installed'. What should I do now ? I don't want to update my Ubuntu OS. I have disabled the update option of Ubuntu.

Comment: As it turns out flash is not built into chromium (it is in Google Chrome), follow the instructions of solsTice

Comment: After the executing the command : sudo apt-get purge flashplugin-installer && sudo apt-get install pepperflashplugin-nonfree && sudo /usr/sbin/update-pepperflashplugin-nonfree --install

I got this error: E: Could not get lock /var/lib/dpkg/lock - open (11: Resource temporarily unavailable)
E: Unable to lock the administration directory (/var/lib/dpkg/), is another process using it?

What to do now ?

Comment: You probably still have the ubuntu software centre open or something else that has locked the cache.

Answer (score 0):

A word of warning: disabling security updates for system and applications is not good idea.

Chrome/Chromium browser currently uses PepperFlash build of flash player (specially modified version of Adobe Flash player). The difference between the browser builds is, besides other, that Chrome has PepperFlash build in, but Chromium get it via package `pepperflashplugin-nonfree`.

To disable all updates and keep the browser only (with flash) possible way is:

1. Install Chrome instead of Chromium ( https://www.google.com/chrome/browser/desktop/index.html)
2. Open "Software & Updates" app, select "Other Software" tab and clear all checkboxes except the Google Chrome one (`http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/ stable main`)
3. Enable automatic updates

Answer (score 0):

**In order to install flashplayer in Chromium you can follow the below:**

These instructions are copied from the [Ubuntu wiki](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Chromium/Getting-Flash)

**Step 1, Check to ensure the Multiverse software repository is enabled**

First, one must ensure the Multiverse software repository is enabled. Launch the Ubuntu Software center app if it isn't already running.

[image: Ubuntu Software Centre]

Click **Edit** and then **Software Sources**. Under "Ubuntu Software" tab, mark the "Software restricted by copyright or legal issues (multiverse)" box and close. You will probably need to type your password to do this system-level change.

[image: add repository]

After you turn on this new repository, the system will scan it to learn of new packages. Wait until the progress spinner goes quiet. It may take a minute or two on a slow internet connection. [image: reloading package chache]

**Step 2, install pepperflashplugin-nonfree**

Next, you can simply start the Ubuntu Software Center and get the Pepper Flash Player - browser plugin. The package name pepperflashplugin-nonfree has "nonfree" in the name because it refers to its ownership by Adobe Systems and free-speech qualities, not that it costs money. The browser may ask your permission to run "xdg-open" to launch Ubuntu Software Center.

**Step 3, run installer**

This part may be intimidating because it's unfamiliar, but there's not really any magic here. You're going to run Terminal, paste a command to run, and wait for it to finish before closing the Terminal.

So, tap the Super/Windows button or click the Ubuntu symbol in the upper left and start typing "Terminal", and click on "Terminal" when it appears. [image]
A terminal will appear with your computer name and a blinking cursor. Take a look at it, so you know what it looks like when your computer is not doing anything except waiting for your command. In it, paste sudo update-pepperflashplugin-nonfree and press Enter. That will run a while. [image]
When it's finished, you'll see that computer name and blinking cursor again. Type exit and hit Enter, to quit. You're done! Go enjoy your new flash player. Now close Chromium and start it again.

```
Note

You'll need to restart your browser for the new plugin to take effect.
```